# rename(assets/uploads/AC925972.pdf ,assets/uploads/ABcd.pdf): The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (code: 123)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I write following  code in codeigniter controller in which
  following error show:

> rename(assets/uploads/AC925972.pdf ,assets/uploads/ABcd.pdf): The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (code: 123)

```
$path=AC545.pdf;
$old = "assets/uploads/$path";
$new = "assets/uploads/ABcd.pdf";
rename($old, $new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$path=AC545.pdf;
```

to

```
$path="AC545.pdf";
```